# Using Xming X11 Launcher With Windows SSH Cmdline

Tags: windows-10, command-line, ssh, putty, x11-forwarding

I am trying to use X11 forwarding using the following command while XMing is running (using XLauncher):

```
ssh -X2 user@server:port
```

but it does not set the `DISPLAY` environment variable, which I believe because it did not recognize the X11 forwarding connection. I tried setting it manually to something like: `:0`, `:0.0`, `localhost:10.0`, `localhost:11.0`, `localhost:0.0`, or `some_addr:some_number`, but none of them worked. Then, I tried SSH'ing to my server using Putty, which I did not find problems getting X11 forwarding with it (but I need the SSH session in my Windows cmd-line and not Putty), and then get the value set for `DISPLAY` and set in my other session logged in in my Windows cmd-line SSH. Using the latter method made X11 work for Windows cmd-line SSH, but as soon as I close the other Putty session, I would no longer be able to get the X11 forwarding again.

I need to be able to get X11 forwarding using nothing but the original Windows cmd-line SSH (I don't want to use `plink.exe` as it does not handle CTRL-C, CTRL-D, ...etc., and rather use the default handlers for any binary for such actions (e.g. close plink.exe on ctrl-c)).

Answer (score -1):

So I had the same issue that you have and I found that you have to have an x11 server running on what would be your client machine during the ssh. The reason is that x11 works in reverse the your windows box becomes the server for the x11
Hope this helps